# Fetch only necessary Data from the JSON using model class like concept in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

for an input Json,

```
 [{
            "ID": "00300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "CommonTags": [
                "Sports"
            ],
            "subID": "149f43d0-6fa9-44f3-b4ba-6fb7a320d0a4",
            "Description": "Sports,Arts",
            "Title": "Biodata",
            "index": 1,
            "Value": "Availabity"
        },
        {
            "ID": "00400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "CommonTags": [
                "Social Media"
            ],
            "subID": "149f43d0-6fa9-44f3-b4ba-6fb7a320d0a4",
            "Description": "Sports,Arts",
            "Title": "Biodata",
            "index": 5,
            "Value": "Availabity"
        },
        {
            "ID": "07300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000079",
            "CommonTags": [
                "Sports"
            ],
            "subID": "149f43d0-6fa9-44f3-b4ba-6fb7a320d0a4",
            "Description": "Environmental Science",
            "Title": "Biodata",
            "index": 1,
            "Value": "Performace"
        }
    ]
```

I want only the some necessary fields such as ID,CommonTags,Value.
my approach for this, by the utilization of for loops and fetch and store the necessary values.

Is there any possibility like model we use in ASP.net and get only the necessary values in python.

I'm relatively fresher to python language. Please suggest if there's an alternative to utilization of for loops.

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "00300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "CommonTags": "Sports",
    "Value": "Availability"
  },
  {
    "ID": "00400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "CommonTags": "Social Media",
    "Value": "Availability"
  },
  {
    "ID": "07300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000079",
    "CommonTags": "Sports",
    "Value": "Performance"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glom](https://glom.readthedocs.io) allows you to define a spec (model) to do so.

```
>>> from glom import glom
>>> spec = [ dict(ID='ID', CommonTags=('CommonTags', '0'), Value='Value') ]
```

Result:

```
>>> glom(target, spec)
[{'ID': '00300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  'CommonTags': 'Sports',
  'Value': 'Availability'},
 {'ID': '00400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  'CommonTags': 'Social Media',
  'Value': 'Availability'},
 {'ID': '07300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000079',
  'CommonTags': 'Sports',
  'Value': 'Performance'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension that iterates over the dicts with a dict comprehension that filters the necessary fields seem to do the job:

```
out = [{k: (v[0] if isinstance(v, list) and len(v)==1 else v) for k,v in d.items() 
        if k in ['ID','CommonTags','Value']} for d in lst]
```

Output:

```
[{'ID': '00300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  'CommonTags': 'Sports',
  'Value': 'Availabity'},
 {'ID': '00400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  'CommonTags': 'Social Media',
  'Value': 'Availabity'},
 {'ID': '07300000-0000-0000-0000-000000000079',
  'CommonTags': 'Sports',
  'Value': 'Performace'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexible solution using a `dict` to either map keys of the input dict to the output dict directly or to assign the result of a (lambda) function to a key of the output dict:

```
from typing import Callable

def model_dict(d, mapping):
    return {k: v(d) if isinstance(v, Callable) else d[v] for k, v in mapping.items()}

mapping = {
    "ID": "ID",
    "CommonTags": lambda x: x["CommonTags"][0],
    "Value": "Value"
}

result = [model_dict(d, mapping) for d in lst]
```

Would even work with nested dictionaries, if `model_dict` is called inside the lambda function. Instead of the lambda function, any `Callable` object can be used.